# Using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter possible with a map data structure instead of list?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

In my firebase data structure, I have saved a list of a model class in form of a map, like `HashMap<String, ModelClass>`. Is it possible to use `com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` also with having a map instead of a list, where the `getValues()` list of that map should load the adapter?

```
"xyz": {
    "key1": modelclassobj1
    "key2": modelclassobj2
}
```